# Cucumber disease/ pest identification

Tags: identification, diseases, pests, cucumbers

Can anyone tell me what is happening with this cucumber plant?[image]

Comment: Whatever is happening, I don't think it's a disease. More likely insects and/or sunscald.

Comment: It does look like a disease to me but I'm not able to confirm just by this picture. You can read more to possibly identify the problem here: https://apps.extension.umn.edu/garden/diagnose/plant/vegetable/cucumber/leavesspots.html

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like [striped cucumber beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Striped_cucumber_beetle) damage. Once the beetles get established it is very hard to control them; the adults can move very quickly and can mash up a leaf by poking holes in it in very short time. Then they move on to another leaf. On the upper and lower surfaces of leaves and in flowers is where to find them active. One way to handle the beetles is to grow young plants from seed in a protected environment to get them growing fast and without checks due to cold weather or lack of rain and plant out when they are vigorous into warm soil and watch over them carefully.